# Can quantum algorithm still success if some gates fail and cannot be measured?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I know the power of quantum computation is to simultaneously compute all the qubits if they are entangled. I wonder if the quantum algorithm is still functional if one of the quantum gates fails (thinking the logical qubit disappears) and we only measure the rest of the qubits?